# Finding a way to JOIN a limited number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have come up with the following theoretic solution to a query I want to run:

```
SELECT m.id, u.user_id, COUNT(u.user_id) FROM matches m
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM match_user u1 WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM match_user WHERE match_id = u1.match_id ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 10
    )
) u ON u.match_id = m.id
GROUP BY u.user_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(u.user_id)
```

However, MySQL "doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'" as it tells me.

I want to achieve that only the 10 oldest entries from `match_user` are joined into `matches`. How to achieve this?

Dump of tables w/ dummy data: http://ge.tt/20zOdpL1/v/0

**EDIT**

Per Strawberry's suggestion I tried out SQL Fiddle and put in the dummy data that I am working with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a3e9

Desired output from query contains two columns: `user_id`, `number_of_matches`

`number_of_matches` is the number of times that `user_id` is associated with a match through the `match_user` table.

So far so good:

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(u.user_id)
FROM matches m
JOIN match_user u ON u.match_id = m.id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

The catch is that only 10 players are allowed to line up for each match. We'll use a limit of 3 for the data I've pasted into SQL Fiddle, since there's not enough dummy data for 10.

So I want to limit the joined table to ensure that for each match, we only fetch the 3 oldest entries in `match_user`.

This means that the 3 players (`user_id`) who RSVP'd first (`created_at`) is playing.

Referring to the SQL Fiddle, that should leave out the row from `match_user` with `id`=5 since that is the only case where there are more than 3 users RSVP'ing for a match, and that is the oldest RSVP for `match_id`=2

**Further limit**

If we limit to 2 players per match, two more rows would be excluded from the output. Rows `id`=4 and `id`=7, because those are the oldest for either `match_id`.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to join the matching entries from `match_user` into `matches`, but constrain it to the 10 oldest for each `matches` entry. Say there are 15 entries in `match_user` for the related `matches` entry, I only want to join the 10 oldest of these.

Comment: Something like this would work, but I cannot use the external fields inside a subquery: http://pastebin.com/tsJ9MFTV

Comment: What would the desired result set look like?

Comment: Desired result set, hope it makes sense: https://gist.github.com/egeriis/ce1b0ac300623ba85ec6

Comment: Someday, you're going to discover sqlfiddle. I don't understand the result set. Sorry.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for the tip. Updated my question with a link to a SQL Fiddle and further description. Does that help?

Comment: And the desired result set? (Just the actual rows - before any aggregation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the list of matches (as in your comment) and not some sort of count by `user_id` as suggested in the original question.  In any case, you can add aggregation to the following query, if that is what you really want.

This query uses a `where` clause to get up to 10 user ids for each matchid.  The idea is to count the number of users with a smaller match_id and compare this number to `10`:

```
select mu.match_id, mu.user_id
from match_user mu join
     matches m
     on mu.match_id = m.id
where 10 >= (select count(*)
             from match_user mu2 join
                  matches m2
                  on mu2.match_id = m2.id
             where mu2.match_id = mu.match_id and
                   mu2.created_at <= mu.created_at
            );
```

EDIT:

The following query does the summary by user:

```
select mu.user_id, count(*)
from match_user mu join
     matches m
     on mu.match_id = m.id
where 10 >= (select count(*)
             from match_user mu2 join
                  matches m2
                  on mu2.match_id = m2.id
             where mu2.match_id = mu.match_id and
                   mu2.created_at <= mu.created_at
            )
group by mu.user_id;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a3e9/31).

EDIT II:

How does this work?  Obviously, the interesting part of the query is the subquery in the `where` clause.  This subquery is counting the number of `match_user` records that have a smaller `created_at` date than a given record in the outer query.  You can think of this as being a "loop", although the implementation is not necessarily a nested loop.

The `where` clause in the subquery is the key part of the subquery.  The first clause looks at all records with the same `match_id`.  The second part matches only earlier `created_at` records.  The `count(*)` counts the number and the outer filter keeps a particular record only when there are at most 10 such records.

As I look at the query, I realize the join in the subquery is not necessary, nor in the outer query.  This should produce the same results:

```
select mu.user_id, count(*)
from match_user mu
where 10 >= (select count(*)
             from match_user mu2
             where mu2.match_id = mu.match_id and
                   mu2.created_at <= mu.created_at
            )
group by mu.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Gordon. I do want a count on the user_id though. I find it a bit tough to explain this one, but I have tried updating the question with some more descriptions. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks again. Though the result is not as desired. You can see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a3e9/7

`user_id` 7 should have a count of 2, since that's the earliest user to both matches.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis . . . I was taking the `created_at` field from the wrong table.  This time it is tested.

Comment: Wow, that works @GordonLinoff! Do you mind breaking down how this works? Btw, tried with a larger data set: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ad1/2

Comment: The `matches` table is actually not needed :-) Thank you so much for your help!